# Do z-index and DOM hieararchy require mutual alignment?

Tags: html, css, dom, z-index

I have a code like this (`div`s have absolute positions and overlap each other at least partially):

```
<div style="z-index: 1">
    <div style="z-index: 3">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="z-index: 2">
    <div style="z-index: 4">
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems to work okay in the browsers I need, but somehow it doesn't feel right. So my question is: should I consider another approach or this technique is completely legit?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: What doesn't feel right? You can use whatever order you want, including DOM order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, z-index values are relative to stacking contexts, which do somewhat rely on hierarchy.

As all your `div`s are absolutely positioned and have a z-index that is not auto, every one of them establishes a stacking context for their descendants. So the first inner `div` participates in the first outer `div`'s stacking context, and its z-index is relative to that stacking context. Likewise, the second inner `div` participates in the second outer `div`'s stacking context, and its z-index is relative to that stacking context.

Because they are confined to their own parent stacking contexts, neither of the two inner `div`s is aware of the other. In other words, whatever z-index you set to one inner `div` will never have an effect on the other.

However, assuming everything else is defaulted, the two outer `div`s participate in the same parent stacking context, so the second can be said to have a higher z-index (or higher *stack level*) than the first, and swapping their z-index values will indeed cause the one with the higher stack level to then appear in front of the one with the lower stack level.

All of this is defined clearly in [section 9.9 of CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers), and can be relied on, bugs notwithstanding.